# PHP htmlspecialchars is not working

Tags: php, html-entities

```
<?php  
    $new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);  
    echo $new;  
?>
```

output should be

```
& lt;a href=& #039;test& #039;&gt;Test& lt;/a& gt;
```

but output is

```
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: Why?<br />
There is no link in `$new`

Comment: I have no idea what the input and output examples are supposed to look like. Certainly there is no reason to think that what is actually rendered in the question should come out of `htmlspecialchars` like that. Even after hitting the edit button to see the raw input, I'm none the wiser. StackOverflow provides a "Format this as code" button, use that instead of trying to hand code entities and use non-breaking spaces for indentation.

Comment: <pre><code>azat:~$ php -r "var_dump(htmlspecialchars(\"<a href='test'>Test</a>\", ENT_QUOTES));"
string(45) "&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;"
</code></pre>

Comment: He just failed at posting proper code here on SO.

Comment: Edit your question and post your real code, formatted as code (click the `{}` button or simply indent it with 4 spaces).

Comment: That is my question ... why happen so.

Comment: Did you check the source code or the rendered document? It seems that you did the latter.

Comment: I partially formatted the code. I don't know what your desired/obtained output strings should look like so I cannot format those. Please do it yourself by using the provided code formatting button.

Comment: I've posted a solution to get it to show in the browser. Just convert `&` to `&amp`! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343353/htmlentities-does-not-produce-desired-output-in-laravel/21343756#21343756

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't worry. htmlspecialchars() *is* encoding the < and > characters properly. It is just that when you echo the encoded string to your computer screen, your browser helpfully decodes the characters again. If you view the page source you will see the encoded string.

Comment: +1 If the output appears as `<a href='test'>Test</a>` **in the browser** then `htmlentities` is doing exactly what it's supposed to.