# htmlentities does not produce desired output in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use the htmlentities in a laravel4 controller for example like this

```
$varialble = htmlentities("<p></p>");

echo $variable;

//Output is <p></p>
```

Not the entities version.

Can someone point me how to fix this.

Comment: what about `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Same output mate. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: there is no character which needs encoding as entity for HTML in the input string. Try urlencode or what @kcdwayne exposes

Comment: Urlencode gives me weird characters but what I was looking for was a way to for example convert the "<" to &lt; and so forth for the others. I'm I using the right function?

Comment: Have you tried using Laravel's built in `e` method? http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings

Comment: Yes, I have. Same output as htmlentities. Spits out the original input.

Comment: @LaminSanneh Added the reason and solution. Please check below and accept if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah. This threw me for a loop.

Check this out: [PHP htmlspecialchars is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114579/php-htmlspecialchars-is-not-working)

`Don't worry. htmlspecialchars() is encoding the < and > characters properly. It is just that when you echo the encoded string to your computer screen, your browser helpfully decodes the characters again. If you view the page source you will see the encoded string.` @Peter_Carter

I feel kind of silly for not thinking of this earlier, but to actually display `&lt;` and the like, you need to change the ampersand.

```
$variable = '<p></p>';
$var = '<code>'.htmlentities($variable).'</code>';
$var = str_replace('&','&amp;',$var);
echo $var;
```

That will print it literally:  `&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Here is me pasting the exact same thing without `escaping code in Stack`:  <p></p>

Comment: That was spot on mate. Might seem obvious but hey atleast that's one less problem in the world. Thanks.